# Django how to select foreign value in query

Tags: mysql, sql, django

Having following models:

```
User(models.Model):
    ...
    login = ...

Asset(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

How to select users login in Asset query using django QuerySet capabilities. For example:

```
Asset.objects.extra(select = {'user_login' : 'user__login'})
```

make to return query set with user_login field in each model object

Answer (score 0):

Each `Asset` object already has a foreign key to the user. So you can always access -

```
asset = Asset.objects.get(pk=any_id)
if asset.user.login == 'some_value':
    do_some_magic()
```

Please read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.select_related('user')` to select all assets and related users in a single query. Then simply access it through `asset.user.login`.

```
assets = Asset.objects.selec_related('user').filter(<any filter>)

for asset in assets:
    # no additional queries here, as the user objects are preloaded into memory
    print asset.user.login
```

Comment: `select_related` is unnecessary in this case. You can access `asset.user.login` even without it.

Comment: `select_related` is certainly not unnecessary. Yes, you can access `user` without using `select_related`, but this will result in an extra query for each `Asset` object. As the OP clearly expects to use multiple `Asset` objects ("to return query set with user_login field in each model object"), this is a necessary optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I have found following solution:

```
Asset.object.extra( select = {'user_login' : '`%s.%s`' % (User._meta.db_table, 'login') } ).order_by('user__login')
```

The order_by expression is used to make JOIN on User's model table, than user's login can be accessed in SELECT expression within user_table.login